# DocuSign Integration - Signatory tags removed from the document and sent over to DocuSign got completed with Signature

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I am working on app which has integration with DocuSign. By mistake, I removed the signatory tags from the document and sent it for Signature to DocuSign.

Signer completed the signature, however, signatures were missing from the completed copy.

Is there a way by which we can notify to Signer that there are no Signatory tags present on the document or any suggestions to make sure signatures don't get miss out by the signer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have your app code to inspect, but what you probably did is not include any signing elements (also called tabs or tags) in the envelope for the document(s) and recipient(s) that you did include.
Weather or not you use a template, your API calls can include/ensure that you also have tags for all the recipients.

A signer recipient that does not have any tags will be using the DocuSign "free-form" sighing where they get to place their own tags on the documents and may not sign all documents as you expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot Inbar for quick response!

Can you please provide more insights on - "your API calls can include/ensure that you also have tags for all the recipients." 

Are there any parameters which need to pass while calling the DocuSign API which will point that Signatory Tags in the document is missing ?

Comment: You need to have Tabs elements. Again, I don't have your code, here is a code example that includes these elements that you can see in 8 different coding langs - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/